# Отобразить свою страницу в админке

Tags: python, django, django-admin

Здравствуйте, нужна ваша помощь, как отобразить свою страницу в админке django, что нужно прописать в admin.py ?

страницу добавил в urls.py по ссылке переходит так, а вот отобразить не получается

**urls.py**

```
urlpatterns = [
    url(r'^admin/', admin.site.urls),
    url(r'^admin/otchet/$', statot, name='отчет')
]
```

Вид, как блок Пользователи и группы, только вместо users или group, мое название и ссылка

[image: Вид]

Comment: Что должно быть на этой странице?

Comment: @SergeyGornostaev изменил в вопросе, какой вид должен быть

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Такое делается с помощью переопределения [ModelAdmin.get_urls()](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/ref/contrib/admin/#django.contrib.admin.ModelAdmin.get_urls):

```
class MyModelAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    def get_urls(self):
        urls = super(MyModelAdmin, self).get_urls()
        my_urls = [
            url(r'^my_view/$', self.admin_site.admin_view(self.my_view)),
        ]
        return my_urls + urls

    def my_view(self, request):
        # ...
        return TemplateResponse(request, "sometemplate.html", context)
```